# Magento 2 product and customers not saving "No data to save"

Tags: product, admin, customer, magento-2.1.7, save

I've have the following issue:
Customers are not save on *Save and Continue Edit* and redirect to the Customers overview page with the status code 301

[image]

*Save Customer* is working

On Products there is an similar issue
*Save* is not working and redirects also to the overview page, but with the error notice "**No data to save**" 
This hapend to all product types

[image]

[image]

Other save methodes are working

I tried to increase several php configuration settings `max_input_vars`, `opcache.max_accelerated_files` etc.

Any ideas/advice on how to resolve this?

Comment: you can increase post_max_size value in php.ini and then save product.

Answer (score 1):

The `301` status code is the issue here. This is probably occurring as the store code is not being supplied in the save requests. These are the requests that should be made once a product is saved in admin:

- `catalog/product/validate` (returns `200` code)
- `catalog/product/save` (returns `302` found code)
- `catalog/product/edit` (returns `200` code)

However these are the requests that are being made:

- `catalog/product/validate` (returns `200` code)
- `catalog/product/save` (returns `301` moved permanently code)
- `catalog/product/save` (returns `302` found code)

The error `No data to save` is **only** thrown when no POST data is found in the request (https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.7/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Save.php#L154). It appears that when the request to `catalog/product/save` returns a `301`, the next redirected request to `catalog/product/save` does not contain the POST data. Fix the initial `301` request by setting the store code in apache vhost and this should work.